# How I Can Fix Twice Append On List

Tags: python, list

I was making a sort function on python but its writing the "2" twice how i can fix it ?

```
liste = [10,200,5,2,3]
minimal = []
w = 0
try:
    sayac = 0
    lent= (len(liste)-1)
    while True:
        sayac += 1
        if lent == sayac:
            break
        else:  
            listelen = (len(liste)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i <= liste[w] and i <= liste[listelen] and i <= liste[int(listelen/2)]:
                    minimal.append(i)
                else:
                    pass
            print(minimal)
            lent = (len(minimal)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i == minimal[lent]:
                    liste.remove(i)
                else:
                    pass
except:
    print(minimal)
```

> ```
>  OUT : [2, 3, 2, 5, 10, 200]
>   [2, 3, 2, 5, 10, 200]
> ...
> ```

I have a one 2 on my "liste" value but its writing twice how i can fix it ? my brain is gone now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add multiple `minimal` in the first step, but then remove only the last one from `liste`:

```py
liste = [10,200,5,2,3]
minimal = []
w = 0
try:
    sayac = 0
    lent= (len(liste)-1)
    while True:
        sayac += 1
        if lent == sayac:
            break
        else:  
            listelen = (len(liste)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i <= liste[w] and i <= liste[listelen] and i <= liste[int(listelen/2)]:
                    minimal.append(i)
                    break ##########this line added
                else:
                    pass
            print(minimal)
            lent = (len(minimal)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i == minimal[lent]:
                    liste.remove(i)
                else:
                    pass
except:
    print(minimal)
```

Moreover I would reconsider breaking condition so this would be probably better:

```py
liste = [10,200,5,2,3]
minimal = []
w = 0
try:
    sayac = 0
    lent= (len(liste)-1)
    while True:
        sayac += 1
        if len(liste)==0: ############condition changed
            break
        else:  
            listelen = (len(liste)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i <= liste[w] and i <= liste[listelen] and i <= liste[int(listelen/2)]:
                    minimal.append(i)
                    break #############this line added
                else:
                    pass
            print(minimal)
            lent = (len(minimal)-1)
            for i in liste:
                if i == minimal[lent]:
                    liste.remove(i)
                else:
                    pass
except:
    print(minimal)
```